# How should we be organizing our mule imports in order to maximize loading efficiency and for modularity for munit testing?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, munit

We currently have our mule projects organized where we have our mule flows in several flow files. We find that this helps in allowing us to reuse flows. However, it has an added side-effect. By having dependencies amongst other flow files, we are finding that our munit tests now have to load an extensive number of flow files that slows up our munit tests because we have to load many more files. We also don't want to stick our flows into one huge file either.

We want to know if there is a happy medium or a strategy with how we should be splitting our flow files so that it minimizes the impact of performance when it comes to tests and application loading?

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use a general global configuration xml, where you place all your configurations and endpoint connectors. That way, you will only load the global.xml and not every other flow you are referencing.

Global.xml contains:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/> 
<http:request-config name="REST_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="80" basePath="example" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="REST_Request_Configuration2" host="google.com" port="80"  doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="/translate/v2">
```

On your test suite you only need to load one classpath/xml:

```
<spring:beans>
        <spring:import resource="classpath:global.xml"/>
        <spring:import resource="classpath:workflow_you_are_testing.xml"/>
</spring:beans>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd define the default `mule-config.xml`, with the `connector` configurations and flow file for each task in the project. Doesn't necessarily mean each flow file will contain single flow but flows related to same task conainining `sub-flows` or `private flows` as needed. However, the flow functionality which is reuseable like alert `emails`, `database operations`, put that in separate `commons-config.xml` flow file.

For `unit-testing`, I'd create another `mule-test-config.xml` under `src/test/resources` to contain `mock connectors` like `database` or any other. The connectors to use as it is like `http` or some other, copy them as it is to `mule-test-config`.

Now to test particular flow, you'd need `flow file + mule-test-config + commons-config (if any shared flow)`